# http 1.1 rfc: error final status code after expect 100-continue in persistent connection

Tags: http

[HTTP 1.1 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.1.1) says:

> A client that sends a 100-continue expectation is not required to
> wait for any specific length of time; such a client MAY proceed to
> send the message body even if it has not yet received a response.

Same RFC:

> A server that responds with a final status code before reading the
> entire message body SHOULD indicate in that response whether it
> intends to close the connection or continue reading and discarding
> the request message (see [Section 6.6 of [RFC7230]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.6)).

Everybody know that HTTP1.1 allows multiple requests in same TCP connection.

What can happen if server will not close connection after respond with error final status code on request with "Expect: 100-continue" header:

- If server will read remaining "Content-length" bytes from stream and
  discard them and client will not send body - than ongoing request
  from client will be dropped entirely or corrupted by server.
- If server will read remaining "Content-length" bytes from stream and
  discard them and client will send body - than usage of 100-continue is useless.
- If server will not read and discard remaining "Content-length" bytes from stream and client will send body - than server in the best case will respond with 400 Bad Request and client will receive that response as response on it's ongoing request.
- If server will not read and discard remaining "Content-length" bytes from stream and client will not send body - conversation will continue correctly, but probably you will not be so lucky.

So it seems that according to standard if server or client will not initiate closing connection after send/receive error on request with "Expect: 100-continue" than we receive something like undefined behavior.

And seems that closing connection in this case is the only solution that match  RFC and will lead to deterministic behavior.

Is this conclusion correct?